# How can I make web scraping of a field more difficult?

Tags: 7, javascript, entities

I have a text field that I get with `<?php print render ($content['field'][0]['#markup']); ?>` in node.tpl. I'd like to somehow make loading the markup require a click, and deselecting it to put the placeholder markup back. It's a select dropdown if it matters.

I thought javascript might work, to test if scripts worked in node.tpl I tried

```
var test ="<?php print render ($content['field'][0]['#markup']);?>"; 
document.write(test);
```

but it loaded the markup for every node on the page in one line. My php/js skills are weak so I'm hoping there's a module that might help me. I'm open to any suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this:

```
<div class="hidden-text">
<span class="text-change">Your Placeholder</span>
</div>

<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
(function ($) {
$(function(){
$(".hidden-text").click(function () {
    ($(".text-change").text() === "Your Placeholder") ? $(".text-change").text("<?php print render ($content['field'][0]['#markup']);?>") : $(".text-change").text("Your Placeholder");
});
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: I think something like this may work. It didn't with this field, it's a full html text field with a <select> in it though. Does .text support that?

Comment: forgot to write @

Comment: No, `text()` doesn't render HTML tags, it will show HTML tags as text, so in that case change every `.text` with `.html`...there is an example so you can see the difference between `text()` and `html()`: http://jsfiddle.net/hossain/sUTVg/